# How to customize UIRefreshControl with different image and position?

Tags: ios, customization, uirefreshcontrol

I have been looking around but couldn't find anything good about this.

I would like to customize the default `UIRefeshControl` with different loader, etc. So far I can only change `tintColor` & `attributedTitle` properties and most code I found are just basically creating a new `"pulltorefresh"` effect but what I want is to just use the `UIRefreshControl` and customize it a bit.

Is this possible?

Comment: Here is another thing you can do with refresh control: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773215/how-would-i-create-a-status-message-that-briefly-appears-above-a-uitableview/16867684#16867684

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't add different loader without accessing private APIs, but you can add background image:

```
UIImageView *rcImageView =
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
        [UIImage imageNamed: @"refreshControl.png"]];
[self.refreshControl insertSubview:rcImageView atIndex:0];
```

assuming self is an instance of UITableViewController subclass.

Image size you need is 320x43px (@2x 640x86px), the middle area (approximately 35px) will be covered by the loader animation.

I show application logo there...

Comment: please check this question --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/67056902/15466427

Comment: I just want to set a downward arrow on collectionView before loader that indicates the user pull downward the collectionView to refresh, and dismiss arrow when loader comes out