# Add a custom image to UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I have implemented a UIRefreshControl to enable refresh on a UItableView. It is working fine.

```
refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
stopgif=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self  
selector:@selector(gifstop) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"loadingc9" withExtension:@"gif"];
self.urlImageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
[self.aroundme addSubview:refreshControl];
```

I want to add the custom image to refresh control instead of the default pull down icon. But I cannot find any way to implement it. If anyone knows how to add custom image to a UIRefreshControl please help me out.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588091/how-to-customize-uirefreshcontrol-with-different-image-and-position. In short it's not possible.

Comment: @JohnWoods how to change pulltorefresh icon?

Comment: It's not possible to change the pullToRefresh. You need to implement the control manually if you wish to do this, or you can choose from some of these open source options: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=refresh